# Converting a command line program to a GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I created a python script for a simple call with 19 functions. I'm having problems as it won't work in GUI mode. Do I have to recode the whole thing? I don't know much about GUI. Could someone help me here please. I've tried reading about GUI I'm just lost with the steps.

```
import math
q=1
while q == True:
    print("Please select one option from the menu below: ")
    print("\t 0: Expression Input")
    print("\t 1: Numbers Input")
    print("\t 2: Exit \n")
    op = int(input("Please enter (0 or 1 or 2): "))
    def expression_input(str1):
        num3 = eval(str1)
        return num3

    if op == 0:
        expression = input("Please input the expression for calculation: ")
        num3 = expression_input(expression)
        print(num3)
        q = int(input("Press 1 to continue or 0 to exit:"))
        exit

    elif op == 1:
        s = 1
        while s == True:
            opr = float(input("Please select a method for calculation from 1 to 19 for the required function:\n\n\t1:+\n\t2:-\n\t3:*\n\t4:/\n\t5:power\n\t6:root\n\t7:sin\n\t8:cos\n\t9:tan\n\t10:arccos\n\t11:arcsin\n\t12:arctan\n\t13:log \n\t14:ln \n\t15:factorial\n\t16:hex\n\t17:octal\n\t18:decimal\n\t19:binary\n\t"))
            if opr > 19:
                print("Wrong choice, please reenter the option")
                exit
            elif opr <=4:
                p=1
                numb1=input("Enter the first value for calculation")
                numb2=input("Enter the second value for calculation")
                while p==True:

                    if numb1.isdigit():

                        if numb2.isdigit():
                            numb1=float(numb1)
                            numb2=float(numb2)
                            if opr == 1:
                                result=numb1+numb2
                                print (result)
                            if opr == 2:
                                result=numb1-numb2
                                print (result)
                            if opr == 3:
                                result=numb1*numb2
                                print (result)
                            if opr == 4:
                                result=numb1/numb2
                                print (result)
                            p=0
                            s=0
                            q = int(input("Press 1 to continue or 0 to exit:"))
                            exit
                        else:
                            numb2=input("Sorry, the second value is not a number,please re enter the second value")
                    else:
                        numb1=input("Sorry,the first value is not a number. Please Re enter the first value")

            else :
                t=1
                numb1=input("Enter the first value for calculation")
                while t== True:

                    if numb1.isdigit():
                        numb1=float(numb1)                   
                        if opr == 5:
                            numb2=int(input("Enter the power value for calculation"))
                            result = math.pow(numb1,numb2)
                            print (result)
                        if opr == 6:      
                            result = math.sqrt(numb1)
                            print (result)
                        if opr == 7:      
                            result = math.sin(numb1)
                            print (result)
                        if opr == 8:      
                            result = math.cos(numb1)
                            print (result)
                        if opr == 9:
                            result = math.tan(numb1)
                            print (result)
                        if opr == 10:      
                            result = math.acos(numb1)
                            print (result)
                        if opr == 11:      
                            result = math.asin(numb1)
                            print (result)
                        if opr == 12:      
                            result = math.atan(numb1)
                            print (result)
                        if opr == 13:
                            numb2=float(input("Enter the base value for calculation"))
                            result = math.log(numb1,[numb2])
                            print (result)
                        if opr == 14:      
                            result = math.log1p(numb1)
                            print (result)
                        if opr == 15:      
                            result = math.factorial(numb1)
                            print (result)
                        if opr == 16:
                            numb1=int(numb1)
                            result = hex(numb1)
                            print (result)
                        if opr == 17:
                            numb1=int(numb1)
                            result = oct(numb1)
                            print (result)
                        if opr == 18:
                            numb1=int(numb1)
                            result = float(numb1)
                            print (result)
                        if opr == 19:
                            numb1=int(numb1)
                            result = bin(numb1)
                            print (result)

                        q = int(input("Press 1 to continue or 0 to exit:"))
                        t=0
                        p=0
                        s=0
                        exit

                    else:
                        numb1=input("Sorry, it is not a number. Please re enter")


    elif op==2 :
        q=0
        print ("Thank you for using the program. Bye!")
        exit
    else:


        print("Wrong option, Please re enter again")
        s=0
        exit
```

Comment: Instead of converting your program in one go, start with simple tutorials and continue with them until you feel comfortable with the GUI library you picked. Then you can try and make the GUI version of your program.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this basic layout for tkinter app:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

    def say_hi(self):
        print "hi there, everyone!"

root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

You can use entry widget to get number entries

```
v = StringVar()
e = Entry(master, textvariable=v)
e.pack()
```

The most important thing here will be to create a button for each function in the **init** function
for example....

```
b1=Button(self,text='+')
```

then bind the clicking of the mouse button to a function of say 'add'
function add is:

```
add(self,event):

#your code to add
```

to bind b1 use this syntax:

```
b1.bind("<Button-1>",add)
b1.pack()
```

Bind all buttons to respective functions and you can display the result using message widget.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this case you will need to reprogram the entire calculator. [There are lots of GUI libraries](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) you can pick from. TkInter, wxPython and PyQt are some of the more popular ones.

I suggest finding basic tutorials online and making smaller GUIs before trying to build something more complex like a calculator.

Comment: I got told to use the GUI in Tkinter it would be much easy also can anyone with my script like start some of the code then ill learn from that just its the the way i can learn. however when i reading tutorials i just get lost as lol im new to this

Comment: As san said, [ZetCode](http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/) has a decent beginner's guide to Tkinter. No one here will teach you how to write a GUI, but if you try yourself and get stuck you can ask specific questions.

Comment: cmdlst = ['7', '8', '9', '+', '%',
          '4', '5', '6', '-', '**',
          '1', '2', '3', '*', '//',
          '.', '0', 'CL', '/', '=']

ive started already i just need know how i can put those 19 functions  into the code ive just post there

Answer (score 0):

It would just take you a day to learn to get going with making simple GUI to perform what you want to accomplish in the above code, and its worth it instead of asking someone to code for you. I would recommend do it yourself. I have no knowledge of building GUI once I gave my time and I can now make complex GUI either by Maya command module or by wxPython that I know today, you can go to zetcode website to learn how to build a GUI based application yourself.

Also, spend some time with using classes and then separate the code of GUI from logic by making two classes (the one above you already have working)...

Comment: from  tkinter import *
 
# button text list
cmdlst = ['7', '8', '9', '+', '%',
          '4', '5', '6', '-', '**',
          '1', '2', '3', '*', '//',
          '.', '0', 'CL', '/', '=','HEX','SIN','COS','Bin'] <--- im getting error when i run the GUI whats the cause for this?
 
class MyButton(Button):
 
    backref = None
 
    def Click(self):
        # back reference
        self.backref.BtnCmd(self["text"])